# How can I stop template code from being displayed?

Tags: angularjs

I have a working helloworld type of app but as soon as the page loads the template code is visible for a split second. What is the best way to stop this happening?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from
>   being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form
>   while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the
>   undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be adding a loading image to the post request of the ajax call for the json object from controller. That would show you the loader instead of the code until the data comes from the controller.  Other than that u could look at ngCloak directive:

> [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak)

Answer (score 0):

`ngCloak` is only good till you app stays at `"Hello World!"` stage, but as it grows, `ngCloak` is just another headache in performance bottlenecks of AngularJS.

What `ngCloak` directive actually does is, it adds styles for `ngCloak attribute/class` within `<head>` element and these styles come from AngularJS lib `.js` file. So if your page is quite heavy (not just HelloWorld), those expression template codes wont go way till AngularJS is loaded.

See here: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/8IWriNwkzQ2RWmrrQkwC/

I have delayed 5 seconds to load Angular, and despite having `ngCloak` expressions are visible on the page.

**So how to fix it?**

Add the `class="ng-cloak"` as well to body, and keep this styles withing your CSS file:

```
 [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
 }
```

[Source: Angular Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngCloak.js#L21)

Once angular js is loaded and templates, expressions are compiled, angular removes this class! And everything becomes happy every after.